# Why java can pass multi-dimensional array to methods without specifying any size information

Tags: java, arrays

As far as I know, we can pass multiple dimensional array to a method in Java without size info, like this:

```
void foo(int arr[][][])
```

But in C++, you can only exclude the size of the outer-most dimension, like this:

```
void foo(int arr[][y_size][z_size)
```

Now I understand that in C++, 'arr' will decay to a pointer, so the compiler needs to know how much elements to skip between two pointers.

My question is, what happens underneath Java makes it smarter than C++ on this, so it can distinguish the bounds between elements without knowing the size of each dimension?

Comment: C is passing an address. Java is passing a reference to an array object that knows its contents and size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C is passing an address** to one contiguous area of memory. The recipient needs all but one of the dimensions in order to compute the locations of array elements in memory.

**Java is passing a reference to an array object** that knows its contents and size. A multidimensional array is *not* one contiguous area of memory. The computation made by C does not occur. Instead, the multidimensional array is comprised of multiple 1D arrays. Each level but the last is an array of references to arrays.

Array length is still used by Java during array access. [Every array access is checked at runtime.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) If the requested index is greater than or equal to the length (or less than zero), an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Every array, which is a *run-time object*, in Java has a [`length` property associated with it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

  In C, excluding C99 VLAs, arrays are *only* a compile-time type describing how to *access* objects therein per a particular layout.
- Multi-dimensional arrays in Java are always *jagged* arrays.

  This means that the length per/in the type is not even particularly relevant in Java - every "multi-dimensional array" access goes one array at a time so

  ```
  r = a[x][y][z]
  ```

  is merely

  ```
  a_ = a[x]
  b_ = a_[y]
  r = b_[z]
  ```

  and there is is no dimension-to-linear calculation involved.

Comment: The length is still relevant in Java during access, because of bounds checking.

Comment: @AndyThomas Per the *type* - the length is not part of the type in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In java arrays are objects which effectively consist of a pointer, and the size of the array.
So in java the extra information is included in the array object.